# SignalR and SQL backplaning on Azure - Schema information

Tags: signals, azure-sql-database

We recently attempted to configure SignalR with backplaning on SQLAzure and ran into a couple of problems.

The one which stands out was the automatic creation of the tables which SignalR requires for the backplane.

I presume we could get round this by manually adding the tables into azure, so I was hoping to gather a little information on the Schema required.

From what I can see on our local version, we have 3 tables:

```
SignalR.Messages_0
SignalR.Messages_0_Id
SignalR.Schema
```

What I'm curious about is the significance of the '0' in these tables. Would this increment with the number of hubs? or would simply creating these tables meet the need.

Any information greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [signalr documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server) says: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or later. The backplane supports both desktop and server editions of SQL Server. It does not support SQL Server Compact Edition or Windows Azure SQL Database. (If your application is hosted on Windows Azure, consider the Service Bus backplane instead.)

SQL Server as Backplane is not supported on Azure, I am trying to create my own backplane in order to use my own table as central repository for signalr messages.

If you read the code of the library Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer, says that you can configure the number of tables to store messages in. Using more tables reduces lock contention and may increase throughput. This must be consistent between all nodes in the web farm. Defaults to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was trying to work out what the stumbling blocks were for working on SQLAzure and whether we could circumvent them in some way, albeit manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Azure, you can use a dedicated SQL Server VM (IaaS instead of the SQL Azure DB PaaS option).

Comment: Thanks for the info, that is out longer term plan, I was trying to work out what the reasons were for things not working on Azure and whether we could manually workaround them.